# jquery Alphanumeric plug-in not working onpaste event

Tags: jquery

I try to use the jquery Alphanumeric plug-in http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/ and it works fine.The problem is when I paste
this text `!@#$%^&*()_67890-qwertyuiopasdfghjkl'zxcvbnm,.` the textbox accepted it.

here is my code:

```
$("#<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").alphanumeric({ allow: "'-., " });
```

I tried to changed my code to shown below  but it was not working.

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").onpaste = function() {
  $("#<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").alphanumeric({ allow: "'-., " });
 };
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try alerting something on `.onpaste`... let's see if it gets there..

Comment: yes, it works fine when i try to alert some text.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

look for this on alphanumeric.js

```
$(this).keypress
    (
        function (e)
            {

                if (!e.charCode) k = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                    else k = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);

                if (ch.indexOf(k) != -1) e.preventDefault();
                if (e.ctrlKey&&k=='v') e.preventDefault();

            }

    );
```

then change `keypress` to `keydown` at least this will prevent pasted values...

other than that, I have no other suggestion....

---

**original answer**

try any of this...

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").onpaste = function() {
  $("#<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").trigger('keypress');
 };
```

or

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").onpaste = function() {
  $("#<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").trigger('keydown');
 };
```

or

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").onpaste = function() {
  $("#<%=txtAddCompanyName.ClientID%>").trigger('keyup');
 };
```

Comment: I think this will not suppose to work.Anyway,thanks, i will add a new function to that alphanumeric plug-in.

Comment: For future reference you could do `$(this).trigger('keypress')` inside those, `this` has the meaning you want :)

Comment: ahh thanks nick... I was thinking of that... I was just not sure... :)

Comment: $(this).bind('paste', function() { return false });
       $(this).bind('cut', function() { return false });
       $(this).bind('copy', function() { return false });

  for those who needed to avoid paste,cut, and copy add this on the alphanumeric plugin

Comment: you can post it as answer though... :)